# How to solve a divergent linear system using iterative methods?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I have a matrix A which is symmetric and non-diagonal dominant.  I tried to use Jacobi/Gauss-Seidel/SOR to solve it but it diverges.  Is there any mechanism to condition the matrix for convergence using the same techniques?

Comment: How big is the matrix?

Comment: I need to run it for 100x100 to 4000x4000.

Comment: Why would you solve such small problems iteratively?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel I am learning the technique.